# Tor hidden service settings failing to allow tor.service to start on CentOS/Fedora

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, tor, systemd

I am attempting to set up a Tor hidden service on CentOS 7 (with systemd), using the `tor` package from the EPEL repository.

Previously this was working fine until a few days ago when it stopped working. Nothing on the system was restarted at this time, though automatic updates are enabled via yum-cron so perhaps something updated.

However, for what it's worth, I have also seen this issue on a mostly-stock installation of Fedora Server and on Fedora Workstation.

Now when I attempt to start the tor service with the hidden service lines in the `/etc/tor/torrc` file, it fails to start.

I have been checking error messages using `journalctl -xn`, and they are not consistent - however the primary errors seem to be:

```
Nov 09 22:05:18 hostname tor[7561]: Nov 09 22:05:18.245 [warn] Directory /var/lib/tor/sshservice/ cannot be read: Permission denied
```

and sometimes:

```
Nov 09 22:12:33.119 [warn] /var/lib/tor/sshservice/ is not owned by this user (root, 0) but by toranon (997). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user
```

I have ensured the following about the entire `/var/lib/tor` path, but with no success:

- Directory is owned by user/group `toranon` (default tor user for the
  EPEL package)
- Permissions are set appropriately (I have tried 700,
  770, 600, 660) on the directory.
- SELinux contexts are set appropriately for the directory and I have verified this using `restorecon`.

Other info:

- If I change ownership of the directory to root, I recieve the same "wrong user" message as before, but with the usernames reversed.
- I have attempted to disable SELinux completely and verified that the tor service still does not start.
- The hidden service directory is already populated with the private key and hostname files, and they were created by the tor daemon on this system. This configuration previously fully worked.
- If I completely remove the `HiddenServiceDir` and `HiddenServicePort` lines from the config, tor starts up as expected.

Some potentially helpful output from `/etc/tor/torrc`:

```
# Do not run as client
SocksPort 0 #Run Tor only as a relay and do not create a local SOCKS proxy
SocksPolicy reject *

# Define hidden service for SSH
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/sshservice/
HiddenServicePort 44674 127.0.0.1:22 #Redirect local SSH port to a nonstandard public port
```

`ls -Z` of `/var/lib/tor`:

```
[root@sagan tor]# ls -Z
-rw-------. toranon toranon system_u:object_r:tor_var_lib_t:s0 cached-certs
-rw-------. toranon toranon system_u:object_r:tor_var_lib_t:s0 cached-microdesc-consensus
-rw-------. toranon toranon unconfined_u:object_r:tor_var_lib_t:s0 cached-microdescs
-rw-------. toranon toranon unconfined_u:object_r:tor_var_lib_t:s0 cached-microdescs.new
-rw-------. toranon toranon unconfined_u:object_r:tor_var_lib_t:s0 lock
drwx------. toranon toranon system_u:object_r:tor_var_lib_t:s0 sshservice
-rw-------. toranon toranon unconfined_u:object_r:tor_var_lib_t:s0 state
```

Not sure what might be causing this issue, but I suspect it's something to do with the precise configuration of systemd. I have experimented with commenting and removing some of the lines in the default systemd `tor.service` file, but with no success.

Currently I am attempting to start tor using `systemctl start tor` using the default systemd `tor.service` file shipped with CentOS.

Any ideas? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to start TOR with `service tor start`. Then it runs as `toranon` and permissions are aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few of the fixes that have been posted in answer to this question do work, but with variable rates of success.

One fix I have come across which works consistently is to load a few exceptions into SELinux.

**Step 1**

Create a `tor-selinux-workaround.cil` file with the following content:

`(typeattributeset cil_gen_require tor_t)
(allow tor_t self (capability (dac_override dac_read_search)))`

**Step 2**

Import that file into SELinux with the following command:

`sudo semodule -i tor-selinux-workaround.cil`

This should work flawlessly for up-to-date Fedora and CentOS systems.

**More Info**

For a more complete explanation, see my post here: https://alexhaydock.co.uk/tech/fix-tor-onion-services-on-centos-fedora

Comment: This is a workaround, but if you have to mess with DAC_OVERRIDE it indicates [something else is wrong and the solution lies elsewhere](https://danwalsh.livejournal.com/69478.html). In this case, you'll find it in Alan Eliasen's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/999890/144961). Though to be fair, that's just a more sane workaround. The real fix is to fix systemd...

Answer (score 3):

I just puzzled through this problem myself, no thanks to systemd's horrible lack of debugging ability.

It turns out that systemd was interfering in my case.  It was allowing the `toranon` user to read  `/var/lib/tor/` but not its subdirectory `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service` on startup.  Thus, if I started up tor as root using the same command it would work, but starting under systemd caused it to fail cryptically.  The permissions on the directory were correct, which was all the more baffling.

The way I fixed the problem was to change my `torrc` file write the hidden service files to a directory that systemd allowed the process to write.  That is, you may be able to change your line from:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/sshservice/
```

to

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/
```

and everything may finally work.

The other option would probably be to tell systemd to allow the process to read the subdirectory by changing the systemd configuration file for `tor.service`, likely in:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/tor.service
```

And changing the `ReadWriteDirectories` option to include the subdirectory you're creating, possibly by adding a line:

```
ReadWriteDirectories=/var/lib/tor/sshservice/
```

Or adding that path as a space-separated list to one of the existing entries in that file.  (It already has two different `ReadWriteDirectories` lines but I'm not sure if the second one works as no logs are getting written.)  According to the documentation for systemd, the entry should be a space-separated list of absolute paths like:

```
ReadWriteDirectories=/var/lib/tor /var/lib/tor/sshservice /var/log/tor
```

Although I haven't tried making this more obscure change, silently hoping that systemd will die in a fire so we don't have to maintain a third set of files and permissions.

Comment: Thanks! Can confirm that the same solution you opted for also works for me. I had hoped to use the method that involved editing the systemd service file (as this current solution will only work for a single hidden service), however that didn't seem to work for me. I can verify that having multiple instances of `ReadWriteDirectories` vs concatenating them on a single line does not make any difference though - systemd seems to concatenate them itself (as seen when you run `systemctl show tor` after running a `systemctl daemon-reload`). I'll keep playing around and let you know if I succeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to start and stop tor using `systemctl`, then the best course of action is to resist modifying the security configuration that's shipped by default.

There should be a file on your system located in the apparmor directory called system_tor, located here : `/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor`

If you look into this file you should see a list of directories that tor is already pre-configured to work with. Here's what my working and default version of the file contains:

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
#include <tunables/global>

profile system_tor flags=(attach_disconnected) {
  #include <abstractions/tor>

  owner /var/lib/tor/** rwk,
  owner /var/lib/tor/ r,
  owner /var/log/tor/* w,

  # During startup, tor (as root) tries to open various things such as
  # directories via check_private_dir().  Let it.
  /var/lib/tor/** r,

  /{,var/}run/tor/ r,
  /{,var/}run/tor/control w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/socks w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/tor.pid w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/control.authcookie w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/control.authcookie.tmp rw,
  /{,var/}run/systemd/notify w,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  #include <local/system_tor>
}
```

If you look at the first directory path that shows up, you'll see
`owner /var/lib/tor/** rwk,`
Note the double astrix. This effectively says that the tor service is allowed to read and write to whatever folders and files are located inside `/var/lib/tor`

You should also see the path located in your `tor.service`, or depending on the version, your `tor@default.service` file. Here's what the `tor@default.service` looks like by default in my current working version:

```
[Unit]
Description=Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
After=network.target nss-lookup.target
PartOf=tor.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=tor.service

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
PIDFile=/run/tor/tor.pid
PermissionsStartOnly=yes
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -Z -m 02755 -o debian-tor -g debian-tor -d /run/tor
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0 --verify-config
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP ${MAINPID}
KillSignal=SIGINT
TimeoutStartSec=300
TimeoutStopSec=60
Restart=on-failure
LimitNOFILE=65536

# Hardening
AppArmorProfile=-system_tor
NoNewPrivileges=yes
PrivateTmp=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
ProtectHome=yes
ProtectSystem=full
ReadOnlyDirectories=/
ReadWriteDirectories=-/proc
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/lib/tor
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/log/tor
ReadWriteDirectories=-/run
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SETUID CAP_SETGID CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH
```

With all of this in mind, what you want your `torrc` hidden service configurations to look like is this:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/sshservice
HiddenServicePort 44674 127.0.0.1:22
HiddenServiceVersion 3
```

You will then need to pre-configure the directory so that tor can use it properly. This process would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mkdir /var/lib/tor/sshservice
sudo chown -R toranon:toranon /var/lib/tor/sshservice # some versions use debian-tor instead of toranon
sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/tor/sshservice
```

Before you're able to run tor using the systemctl command, you may have to first run it manually to generate the required hidden service files. This may be a bug on my particular instance. Do this like so:

`sudo -u toranon tor`

Once you do that, kill the tor process with `ctrl+c` or by using the `kill` command.

You should now be able to start and stop tor using either the `systemctl` command or the `system` command.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add **CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH** to the `CapabilityBoundingSet` of the systemd service:

*/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tor@xxx.service*

```
@@ -30,7 +30,7 @@
 ReadWriteDirectories=/run/tor
 ReadWriteDirectories=/var/lib/tor
 ReadWriteDirectories=/var/log/tor
-CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SETUID CAP_SETGID CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
+CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SETUID CAP_SETGID CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH
 PermissionsStartOnly=yes

 [Install]
```

(changing `ReadWriteDirectories` was not required)

- /etc/centos-release: *CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)*
- systemctl --version: *systemd 219*
- tor --version: *Tor version 0.2.8.7.*
- selinux: disabled

If selinux is enabled, tor still does **not** work! */var/log/audit/audit.log*:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1475960766.994:123): avc:  denied  { dac_override } for  pid=2317 comm="tor" capability=1  scontext=system_u:system_r:tor_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:tor_t:s0 tclass=capability
type=AVC msg=audit(1475960766.994:123): avc:  denied  { dac_read_search } for  pid=2317 comm="tor" capability=2  scontext=system_u:system_r:tor_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:tor_t:s0 tclass=capability
```

Follow https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1292626 to fix that.

The above seems to be required only, if hidden services are used.

Comment: If you read carefully, you're advised to not use `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH`. It's far better to relax perms for the folder, and adding root to the allowed groups to access dirs.

Answer (score 0):

on Debian Jessie, this worked for me (I store tor hidden service information in /opt/tor)

edit /etc/tor/torrc by adding appropriate HiddenServiceDir and HiddenServicePort directives:

> HiddenServiceDir /opt/tor/
>
> HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080

edit /lib/systemd/system/tor@default.service ,
add this line at the end of file:

> ReadWriteDirectories=/opt/tor

create directory and set ownership and permissions:

> mkdir /opt/tor
>
> chown debian-tor. /opt/tor
>
> chmod go-rwx /opt/tor

reload service configuration:

> systemctl daemon-reload

and start service:

> systemctl start tor